# How to handle REST property removals with Java/Jackson?

Tags: java, rest, jackson

I have a REST API that is able to update a user object:

> { "username": "joedoe", "emailAddress": null }

The username is mandatory and the emailAddress is optional.

It should be possible:

1. update the username and emailaddress
2. only update the username
3. remove the emailaddress field

**1:**

> { "username": "joedoe", "emailAddress": "joedoe@anywhere.tld" }

**2:**

> { "username": "joedoe" }

**3:**

Jackson would transform this JSON to a POJO in which the emailAddress field is null. What options are available in order to distinguish the update to the username from a request in which the emailAddress is set to null.

My current implementation will omit updates to field that are set to null.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON there is a [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) for patching object. You can use it in your REST API. Remove is the operation that you want to use in other to suppress the email property from  your object.